Is it madatory to obtain an ethical clearance from my affiliated institute for an interview that is to be presented in a conference?
I'm a research scholar and I'll be presenting a paper related to publishing industry. I'm yet to interview concerned participants. I have obtained consent from them through a consent form. But I haven't obtained an ethical clearance from my affiliated institute.

You need to say more. What is the field? Who are the "participants"? Are the subjects of a study? You might need to say where this is taking place. Please edit the post.

For your sake, it would be good to ask your local IRB and submit an official request if they say you should.

The manner of publication is not relevant. Where did your consent form come from? Did someone approve it?

This question would be improved by editing to providing additional details, especially the jurisdiction, given that it asks if something is mandatory rather than ethical or professionally prudent.

https://irb.tcnj.edu/international/ has a high level overview of human subject requirements across the world. The chance of the OP being in a jurisdiction that did not have such requirements is slim at best.

At a typical US institution you would be expected to either A) get IRB agreement that you do not need IRB approval (typically through an expedited review process) or B) get IRB approval. There is no scenario where you can decide on your own. Researchers have a conflict of interest between 1) all the professional benefits they get from performing/publishing research plus administrative burdens of applying for approval and 2) the protection of research participants. That makes them the wrong people to make decisions on their own about what does and does not need review.
Wherever you are it will depend on local laws and institutional regulations (as well as requirements by the conference). If unsure, ask. There is someone at your institution who has the job of knowing these things.

To resolve the apparent self-contradiction of option A, this often is the difference between "expedited review" and "full board review".  Perhaps rephrase to "A) get expedited IRB confirmation that you do not need IRB review or B) get IRB review"

@BenVoigt The self-contradiction was somewhat intentional in that the main point is "you must consult the IRB" but I have revised to be more clear.
